# FullCalendar remove all event sources after using addEventSource

Tags: html, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm using FullCalendar v4 to make a planning tool. Because some months have a lot of events I only get the first 200. This makes the initial load a lot faster. When I scroll down and reach the bottom of the calendar I call the addEventSource method. Every time I call this method I get the next 200 events. I use jQuery to increase the offset value for the mysql script by 200 each time. When all events for that month are downloaded I can call the addEventSource again, but it will return an empty array as expected. This works great in the month the calendar opens.

But if I go to the previous, of next month it will get all the event sources I got for the month before. It will get the events with an offset of 200, 400, 600, 800 and so on, depending on the number of times I scrolled to the bottom the month before. This way all the events are loaded the first time which makes it slow.

I need a way to remove the event source I added right after this happens. Or remove all event sources when I click on the previous or next button. And I can't figure out how to use the eventSource.remove() method to do this.

This is my code to add an event on scrolling.

```js
var recentScroll = false;
$('#calendar .fc-scroller').off().on('scroll', function() {
  if (!recentScroll && $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
    var offset = localStorage.getItem("offset");
    offset = parseInt(offset) + 200;
    localStorage.setItem("offset", offset);
    recentScroll = true;

    window.setTimeout(() => {
      recentScroll = false;
    }, 2000)

    var event = {
      url: 'load_select_test1.php',
      method: 'POST',
      extraParams: function() {
        return {
          cursus_id: localStorage.getItem("cursus_select"),
          evenement_id: localStorage.getItem("evenement_select"),
          locatie_id: localStorage.getItem("locatie_select"),
          trainer_id: localStorage.getItem("trainer_select"),
          resource_select: localStorage.getItem("resource_select"),
          omgeving_id: localStorage.getItem("omgeving_id"),
          offset: offset
        };
      },
      failure: function() {
        alert('er ging iets mis bij het ophalen van de gegevens');
      }
    };

    calendar.addEventSource(event)
    eventSource.remove(event)
  }
});
```

I've used the .off() for the scroll function to unbind the previous event handlers. And I used the eventSource.remove() method. But this didn't fixed the problem.

I also call the eventSource.remove() method on the previous and next buttons. But that doesn't fix it either.

```
$('.fc-icon-chevron-left').off().on("click", function() { 
  eventSource.remove()
});
```

Because the offset variable for the mysql script is increased with 200 every time I would like to remove all event sources so I'm sure they are all gone. How can I use this?

Comment: Aside from the problem you need to remove `async: false` from the AJAX request. It's incredibly bad practice, to the point where the browser will be showing you a warning in the console telling you not to use it

Comment: `eventSource` appears to be undefined in your code. You need to run [getEventSourceById](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEventSourceById) to return a valid event source instance, and then call remove on that. (Of course you'll also need to give your event source an ID to begin with.)

Comment: @ADyson, thank you for your response. I've been looking to what you suggest. With the getEventSources() method I see the id's are empty. But I can't figure out how to add an id to a new event source. The documentation is not clear for me.

Comment: Just add it when you create the event source, same as you add all the other properties. i.e. `var event = {
      url: 'load_select_test1.php', id: 1, method: 'POST',` ...etc. It's mentioned in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source-object

Comment: @ADyson, thanks again! Now this part works.